# Issue with multiple tab divs on one page

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

Apologies if this answer is already on here, I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Basically, within the main body of a page I want to have tabs for Intro, Calendar, Booking Form etc... which all displays fine, however, the side navigation already has a tabbed element for news, events, documents relating to the subject of the page and, on this page alone, this doesn't display correctly.

I assume this is because of a conflict between the two tab divs and I've tried given them inique IDs in the CSS and html but neither seems to fix the issue so hopefully someone here can point out my error.

HTML for body tabs (content removed to make it easier to view here):

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
    <li>
        <a href="#tabs-1">Introduction</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tabs-2">Fields</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tabs-3">Availability</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tabs-4">Rates</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tabs-5">Ts &amp; Cs</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tabs-6">Bookings</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
content
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    content
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    content
</div>
<div id="tabs-4">
    content
</div>
<div id="tabs-5">
    content
</div>
<div id="tabs-6">
    content</div>
```

And this is the HTML for the side navigation:

```
<div id="tabs">

                        <ul class="tabs clearfix">
                            <li class="tabs-1"><a href="#tabs-1" title="News">News</a></li>
                            <li class="tabs-2"><a href="#tabs-2" title="Documents">Documents</a></li>
                            <li class="tabs-3"><a href="#tabs-3" title="Links">Links</a></li>
                            <li class="tabs-4"><a href="#tabs-4" title="Events">Events</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="block tabs_holder">

                            <div id="tabs-1">
                                <ul class="listing">
                                    {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{embed:related}" orderby="entry_date" sort="DESC" limit="10" dynamic="no"}
                                        <li><a href="/news/view/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>
                                        {if no_results}
                                            <li>{related_no_content}</li>
                                        {/if}
                                    {/exp:channel:entries}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tabs-2">
                                <ul class="listing">
                                    {exp:channel:entries channel="document" category="{embed:related}" orderby="entry_date" sort="DESC" limit="10" dynamic="no"}
                                        <li><a href="/document/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>
                                        {if no_results}
                                            <li>{related_no_content}</li>
                                        {/if}
                                    {/exp:channel:entries}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tabs-3">
                                <ul class="listing">
                                {exp:channel:entries channel="links" category="{embed:related}" orderby="entry_date" sort="DESC" limit="10" dynamic="no"}
                                    <li><a href="{link_url}" {if "{link_target}"=="y"}target="_blank"{/if}>{title}</a></li>
                                    {if no_results}
                                        <li>{related_no_content}</li>
                                    {/if}
                                {/exp:channel:entries}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tabs-4">
                                <ul class="listing">
                                {exp:channel:entries channel="events" category="{embed:related}" orderby="entry_date" sort="DESC" limit="10" dynamic="no"}
                                    <li><a href="/events/view/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>
                                    {if no_results}
                                        <li>{related_no_content}</li>
                                    {/if}
                                {/exp:channel:entries}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--/tabs_holder-->
                    </div>
```

Many Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't name your DIV with the same IDs! Whatever is your name, they must be different (and all the sub items also).

Comment: I'd realised that, what I wasn't sure about was all the places I needed to change it, had to update the CSS and jquery code as well, eventually managed to get it working and displaying correctly . Thanks anyway

Comment: Not easy to help without all items (CSS, full html ordered...)

Answer (score 1):

You should tell the page script about the tabs. Lets say you have 2 tab sets,  and , of course the ids must be different, declare it inside script tags:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            $("#tabs2").tabs();
    });
</script>
```